# How to make just a part of html 'tabbable'? (Modal Dialog)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have an Angular App and a custom Modal Dialog implementation. How can I limit the 'tabbablity' of the page so that i can just tab through the Modal, and not everything else in background?

I have set `aria-hidden="true"` for all other elements directly under the body tag, and thought that has to handle that, but no success. `tabindex="-1"` also did not work..

Actually I want the exact tab-behaviour of this bootstrap modal:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Click: "launch demo modal" and tab through the modal elements..

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I look at the bootstrap modal, and they do not set anything to other elements, but just to the modal container div (with `class="modal fade show"`) `tabindex="-1"`. And after the last element in modal, tab sets focus to this modal container div. After that the focus is set again to the first modal element. In my case `tabindex="-1"` strangely does not bring anything, after the last element focus jumps to the Browser's URL Input field and goes on.

Comment: did you let overlay (backdrop) option?

Comment: no i have a modal-backdrop, but i don't think that has sth. to do with it.. bootstrap also does not make anything with backdrop regarding tabbing. You can also remove the backdrop from bootstrap modal in developer tools, and tab through the modal again.. it still works

Comment: In example of bootstrap `<div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" ...` do what's you want, as `<div class="modal fade show" ...` (without tabindex) go to background elements (tab key)

Comment: I have already tried it. please read the question carefully (@see Edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what code you have...but this tabindex behavior works well with bootstarp example.

```css
.modal-backdrop {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal (with tab only on modal elements)
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        coucou
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
  Launch demo modal (with tab on all document elements)
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        coucou
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thank you.. strange that here it does not behave like that.. so actually tabindex="-1" should be everything i need..

Comment: It's only part of code i removed. I see also backdrop at end of document `<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>` who have css `z-index: 1071;`. Maybe it's also what do the trick. And if you remove background color of class `modal-backdrop`, you could have a 'transparent" backdrop.

Comment: after i remove the backdrop element completely, it still works. so i think the tabindex is the only thing.. which strangely does not work here

Comment: Glad to help :-) and hope you can find where glitch is